# gwt sample project rpc call failure

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

When i try to run gwt sample project it gives "RPC call failure.An error occurred while attempting to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again". It was running good before but after i update programs and libraries it gives that error. Which update causes this error or there is other things?

Appengine version:1.7.0
GWT version:2.4.0
Eclipse version:4.2(juno)
JDK version:1.7.0_05

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem you are facing but it seems to be the most frequent problem.

Let me predict - you last tried GWT four years ago and you hoarded the sample project hoping to pull it out one day.

And yesterday, you did pull it out. It kinda worked and then you decided to upgrade to the latest 2.4.0. (Actually the latest is 2.5.0-rc1).

Ooops. The web-inf/lib of your project is still faithfully using pre-version 2.2 gwt-servlet jar.

Nope, you can't do that. GWT-RPC data transfer format is version-unstable. Not guaranteed to be compatible from one version to the next.

Simple solution - recreate a new GWT project using the new Google plugin.
Then copy the src and web.xml of your project into the new project.

Or replace the gwt-servlet.jar with the latest. And if you usegwt-servlet-deps.jar, you would need to upgrade that too (but I doubt so, because if you did use gwt-servlet.deps.jar you wouldn't be asking this question).

**But why** would you keep the gwt sample from an old project?

The samples have remained quite the same over the years. Why not use the samples from the new GWT 2.4.0 download. You don't have to keep the samples. You should try to construct the projects for the samples afresh.

The GWT directory is found under Eclipse's plugins directory, under a long name. Like

plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205091048-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0.

In which you will find the samples directory.